# Zenoir Administrator Module access

Tags: codeigniter

I try to run the [Zenoir project](https://github.com/anchetaWern/Zenoir-Online-Classroom). I got stuck in the first interface because I do not know the access settings for an Administrator Module.
any help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved using the users table in the database and especially by changing one type to 1 which refers to an administrator.